# C++ Conventions: this pointer

Tags: c++

I am curious to know, is there a convention to the usage of this-> in C++? I generally like to use this-> to emphasize that a method and/or variable is a member of the containing class, but it does look rather unappealing, visually speaking. It'd also be awesome to know about any other C++ coding conventions often seen in industry, e.g. Camel case vs. underscores, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: No one cares as long as you're consistent. If people do care then they need to stop caring. Also, unfortunately this question is not suited for [so]. Consider reading the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: Could you elaborate as to how this question is not suitable for StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am curious to know, is there a convention to the usage of this-> in C++?

I personally avoid the this-> pointer whenever possible but that's just personal preference.

> It'd also be awesome to know about any other C++ coding conventions often seen in industry, e.g. Camel case vs. underscores, etc.

Coding conventions largely vary but one example is Google's [comprehensive C++ Style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html).

- "[Filenames should be all lowercase and can include underscores (_)
  or dashes (-).](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#File_Names)"
- "[Variable names are all lowercase, with underscores between words. Class member variables have trailing underscores.](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Variable_Names)"
- "[Regular functions have mixed case; accessors and mutators match the name of the variable](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Function_Names)"

And, my favorite:

- "[You're not really going to define a macro, are you? If you do, they're like this: MY_MACRO_THAT_SCARES_SMALL_CHILDREN.](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Macro_Names)"

Comment: The Google C++ style guide doesn't seem to mention anything about the `this` pointer.

Comment: @BugalugsNash I didn't mean to imply that it did. I just referred to the Google style guide to answer the second part of the question. I've edited my answer to hopefully make that more clear.